# Merge two large dataframes and remove difference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have two `pandas` dataframes `pre` and `post` data (example) looks like this

```
post = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['NM001.1:c.05C>T','NM002.1:c.05C>T','NM003.2:c.05G>T','NM004.1:c.05T>C', 'NM004.1:c.05T>C', 'NM004.1:c.05T>C'],'Allele':['T','T','T','C', 'A', 'G'],'Score':[1,7,8,9,4,8]})

pre = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['NM001.1:c.05C>T','NM002.1:c.05C>T','NM004.1:c.05T>C'],'Location':['5.1','7.2','3.1'],'infer':['Path','Ben','Path']})
```

Real data dimensions are
`shape` of `pre` data is 16448, 23 and `post` is 16771, 738

For the example data
`shape` of `pre` data is 3, 3 and `post` is 6, 3

I have tried

```
total = pd.merge(pre, post, on=['ID'], how="right")
```

and

```
total = pd.merge(pre, post, on=['ID'], how="inner")
```

and

```
total = pd.merge(pre, post, on=['ID'], how="left")
```

For example data when i check the `total` using `value_counts` one of the `ID` which has 3 occurrence in both dataframes is being multiplied resulting in 9 occurrence which is supposed to be only 3
`total['ID'].value_counts()`
`NM004.1:c.05T>C    9`

None of it gives the reqired data, the desired output data `shape` is 16448, 760 (for the example data the desired output shape would be 3,5)

for the example data the desired output is

```
total = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['NM001.1:c.05C>T','NM002.1:c.05C>T','NM004.1:c.05T>C'],'Allele':['T','T','C'],'Score':[1,7,9], 'Location':['5.1','7.2','3.1'],'infer':['Path','Ben','Path'] })
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Thank you

Comment: What is the expected output you want with the example dataframes you provided? What are you trying to achieve? Based on your desired output dimensions, I may think you need an `left` `merge` (assuming `pre` goes first), but I can't really tell by the information you provided.

Comment: @jlgarcia, thank you for you response, I have updated the question hope that helps, sorry for the confusion. Yes i have tried the `left` `merge` as you suggested and the did not get the desired output (3,5 dimensions and 16448, 760 for the real data). Thank you

Comment: Your `desired` dataframe is not achiveable by just a simple `merge` operation. Take a look at the `NM004.1:c.05T>C` `ID` in both `pre` and `post` dataframes. It is repeated 3 times in `post` dataframe, so , no matter what type of `merge` you perform, you will have this `ID` 3 times in your output dataframe (one for each `Score|Allele` row in `post` dataframe. To achieve your desired dataframe, you will need first to define a criterion to select one row in the `post` dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the previous comments, you can't achieve your expected output by a simple `merge` operation, since you have a matching `ID` with 1 and 3 apparitions in your dataframes, which will result in 3 rows with the same `ID` in the merfed dataframe.

Assuming there's not another criterion, you can achieve your expected output by symply dropping the duplicated merged rows:

```
total = pd.merge(post, pre, on = 'ID', how = 'left')
total = total.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'])
```

Output:

```
ID  Allele  Score   Location    infer  
NM001.1:c.05C>T T   1   5.1 Path  
NM002.1:c.05C>T T   7   7.2 Ben  
NM004.1:c.05T>C C   9   3.1 Path
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) your both *dataframes* this way :

```
def f(df, col="ID"):
    return [col, df.groupby(col).cumcount()]

total = post.merge(pre, left_on=f(post), right_on=f(pre)).drop("key_1", axis=1)
```

Output :

```
print(total)

                ID Allele  Score Location infer
0  NM001.1:c.05C>T      T      1      5.1  Path
1  NM002.1:c.05C>T      T      7      7.2   Ben
2  NM004.1:c.05T>C      C      9      3.1  Path
```